# What are some alternatives to Shazam for iOS?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications, audio

What are some good alternatives to Shazam?

Comment: for what phone/device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I hear a song and I want to know the name of it, I use [SoundHound](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id284972998?mt=8) on my iphone. So far it has identified all of the songs I've searched. Even if for some reason I don't have network access, it will store the search and you can send it to their servers once connectivity is restored.

By the way, SoundHound and Midomi are the same thing. Midomi changed its name to SoundHound.

Answer (score 1):

When I had a Blackberry on the Verizon, it had a free app pre-installed on the phone called "V-Cast Music" that would ID songs for me. Was surprisingly good and would even ID less common tracks like music you hear in the electronica genre.

There's plenty of apps for the iPhone like:

[MusicID](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/musicid-with-lyrics/id320029865?mt=8)

and

[SoundHound](http://download.cnet.com/SoundHound-for-iPad-and-iPhone/3000-2133_4-10863038.html)

I haven't tried them personally, but they seem to get good reviews.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Midomi](http://www.wired.com/listening_post/2008/07/midomi-iphone-a/) app as well I guess.